# Why did the robots run away?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the end of the epic fight scene with Ultron robots run and fly away from Hulk like they have emotions and fear. Their goal is to get to the drill, isn't it? Why did they behave like people?

Comment: IIRC they'd already eradicated Ultron "from the internet" so he was only left in his physical forms. They were probably trying to escape to keep Ultron alive as there was no other way

Comment: For those who downvoted: please answer and explain the reason.

Comment: I agree that it would be ideal if people explained downvotes - but they are not obliged to do so.  People might just think the question is not interesting.

Comment: @iandotkelly I'm just asking. I just want my questions to be appropriate for everybody.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as [TheLethalCarrot](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96087/why-did-robots-ran-away#comment162526_96087) suggested, it was a tactical retreat keep Ultron alive. After he was born and the Avengers questions his allegiance, Vision explained how even Ultron's forms had to be destroyed

> Vision: What will you do? [he looks at them all realizing they will destroy him] I don't want to kill Ultron. He's unique, and he's in pain. But that pain will roll over the earth, **so he must be destroyed. Every form he's built, every trace of his presence on the net,** we have to act now. And not one of us can do it without the others. Maybe I am a monster. I don't think I'd know if I were one. I'm not what you are, and not what you intended. So there may be no way to make you trust me. But we need to go. [he holds up Thor's hammer and hands it to him, Vision walks off and everyone stares in shock]

Source: [Transcripts Wikia > Avengers: Age of Ultron](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron)

Vision had already cut off Ultron's access to the Internet so he could not escape to there. after effectively destroying his Vibranium body Ultron knew he was about to be killed since the drones aren't string and the Avengers have been tearing them apart, so he would have then ordered the drones to flee since Ultron can live in any one of them. [we know at least one got away but Vision ultimately took care of that one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiwlOQseLOY)

*"But what about the Vibranium body? Hulk just punched it, it wasn't destroyed!"*

yeh but Tony, Vision and Thor would not have stopped attacking if it wasn't on the brink and considering how hard Hulk can punch it unlikely to function at all. even if the Vibranium body could after that kind of impact given how damaged it was already it's not surviving the fall. the fact the the drones began to flee is another sign that the Vibranium body was finished

Comment: Good to know my memory of the film wasn't completely wrong.

Comment: Forgive me if i'm remembering this incorrectly, but his body wasn't made of Vibranium... he stole the Vibranium from Klaue which he intended to use to build his perfect body, which was then stolen and became Vision. so none of his bodies actually had any vibranium in them

Comment: @BladeWraith actually his last one did. [from the wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ultron) *"With all his plans of creating a perfect form being thwarted, Ultron decided on a compromise in which **he used parts of the remaining vibranium to create a more durable robotic body** while using the rest of the vibranium to strengthen the core structure of his device"*. also if you use the text find to look for that part you'll see an image subtitled *"Ultron reveals his vibranium covered body"*